# Replace all particular values in a data frame with entry that depends on row and column of value

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a number of missing values that can be calculated from existing values in the dataset. I want to go update each NA with the output of a function that requires the row and column of the input to perform the calculation.

Want I need is something like:

```
df[df == NA] = func(row(NA), col(NA))
```

Though I know this doesn't work. Is there a way for R to access the row and column of each NA as it updates them?

I know this could be done with nested for loops and if statements, but there must be a much less computationally intensive way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `df == NA` use `is.na(df)`. And see if `which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)` solves the `fun` issue. Can you post sample data? If you can, post the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` in the question, please.